# Sorting "dynamic" columns after reading them from a file in c++.

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

A text file has for example 15 columns with data but only three of them (columns) are important for further calculations. Now i would like to read all the columns via **ifstream** and then create a new file with just the *important* columns (in this case three).

```
std::vector<double> column1;        
std::vector<double> column2;        
std::vector<double> column3;

double col1;
double col2;
double col3;

double sortCol1;
double sortCol2;
double sortCol3;

void readingFile()
{
    // at very first the user is able to see the data of the file and decide which columns are needed. 
    std::cout << "Which columns do you need?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> col1;  // for example column 3
    std::cin >> col2;  // column 5
    std::cin >> col3;  // and column 9

    std::ifstream file("testFile.txt"); //reading the file
    if(!file)                         
    {
        std::cerr << "* Can't open file! *" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {   // this is the point which i don't get. 
        // How do i specify "dynamic" which column i need?
        // somethimes i need to pushback sortCol7 to column1 sometimes sortCol3 to column1 and so on. 
        while(file >> sortCol1 >> sortCol2 >> sortCol3 ... and so on...)
        {
            // i think i need an if-statement here with conditions like: 
            // col x = sortCol x 
            column1.push_back(sortCol1);
            column2.push_back(sortCol2);
            column3.push_back(sortCol3);
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

It is important to know that the format of the data files is variable. So im not able to write a static code which pushes every time the same columns in the same vector.

Comment: use `std::stringstream` ?

Comment: The traditional approach to aggregating data is to use a std::vector.  There is nothing that says you can not have a std::vector of std::vectors.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb i can of course have a vector of vectors. `std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix`. Apart from this there is no need to store vectors in vectors. I'm trying to store numbers in vectors. I'm stucking at the point where i allocate the input from `std::cin >>` to `sortCol`

Comment: If you have a file containing a number of rows of columns and you want to select some arbitrary columns, you have a matrix and you want to address the columns by index.  If that's not what you have, you'll need to choose some other way to describe your data.

Comment: @KostasRim would you please explain your suggestion in more detail?